# How to convert Oracle Date format to Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, sqldatatypes

I have an Oracle Date type stored in the db in this format `06-MAR-20`, when i mapped it to a java domain class i had a property of type

```
java.SQL.Date
```

but i got the data in this format

```
2020-03-06
```

How can i stick to the exact same format from whats stored in my db?
Will

```
java.SQL.Timestamp
```

keep it the same?

Or do i need to do some configuration when getting the data from query to maintain its format?

Comment: I recommend you neither use `java.sql.Date` nor `java.sql.Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead retrieve a `LocalDate` from your database. It’s from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And as others have said, it cannot have a format, so don’t worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates do not have a specific format. Internally, they are stored as a series of bytes that represent its year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds.

What you are seeing when you look at your date in the database is a string representation whose format depends on nls setting `nls_date_format` of either your session (if it specified one), or of your database (if the parameter was not set at session level).

If you want to fetch your date in format `DD-MON-YY`, you can either use `to_char()` in your query:

```
to_char(mydatecol, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Or you can set it at session level:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YY';
```

Comment: okay im going to try used the to_date function, if i want the month to be capital do i need to add anything else? Also does this mean that the java field that is being mapped to should still be in java.SQL.Date?

Comment: @user13342895: sorry, typo: I meant `to_char()`.

Comment: @user13342895: that would be `DD-MON-YY`.

Comment: Okay, and if i wanted to assign the column a new name say ```select to_char(mydatecol, 'DD-MON-YY') as newColName from aTable;``` is this right or would the as newName be inside first param?

Comment: Okay and did you say i can keep the data type as java.SQL.Date? Would it work if it was timestamp as well?

Comment: @user13342895: I don't know a lot about Java, but I doubt that this maps to a Java date. In Oracle, `to_char()` returns a string.

Comment: Okay I will just map it to a string, thanks

Comment: *I will just map it to a string,* Bad idea, sorry. What do you need that format for? It we can understand, I am sure we can guide you better.

Comment: "Okay, and if i wanted to assign the column a new name say select to_char(mydatecol, 'DD-MON-YY') as newColName from aTable; is this right or would the as newName be inside first param? "   Assigning a column alias is part of the SELECT syntax, It has nothing to do with TO_CHAR.  You can see the doc on to_char at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129.  The nature of your question suggests you are just trying to feel your way through this without even consulting the docs.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

> I have an Oracle Date type stored in the db in this format 06-MAR-20

**No, you don’t.**

- Databases such as Oracle store date-time values with their own internally defined binary values, not as plain text.
- Oracle `DATE` type holds a time-of-day as well as a date.

## `DATE` = date + time-of-day

The [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) type in Oracle database is misnamed. It holds more than a date (year, month, and day-of-month).

This type represents a date with time-of-day resolving to whole seconds. This type lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type cannot be used to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. (To track a moment, use Oracle type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.)

Note that this Oracle naming differs from the SQL standard. In the standard, a `DATE` type is a date-only value, with no time-of-day and no time zone or offset.

## `java.time.LocalDateTime`

So this type maps to [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in Java.

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Storage.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

## Text

Notice that in the code above we are using smart objects rather than dumb strings.

Date-time objects such as `LocalDateTime` are not `String` and do not hold text. They internally represent their value in their own way. You can parse a string as a date-time object, and you can ask the date-time object to generate text. But the text and the date-time object are separate and distinct.

The *java.time* classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = ldt.toString() ;
```

> 2020-01-23T01:23:45.123456789

Parsing.

You can generate text in other formats. You can specify your own custom format by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`. Usually better to automatically format by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-01-23T01:23:45.123456789" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

I felt like you did not search the stackoverflow properly. There are lots of answers related to the problem you mentioned here. That will give you better idea how to tackle the problem.

The above answer can only be used if you are using straight JDBC, but usually enterprise apps will use some ORMs and most of then use it along with spring. Then you may not get the freedom to correct the sql everywhere and writing sql for every domain class is not recommended. So it is better to write custom methods for date properties that you have in your domain to get the date string in whatever format you want. Sample getStringDate(java.SQL.Date) to convert it to the format you want.

```
Date sqldate = new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
System.out.println(sqldate);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
System.out.println(format.format(sqldate));
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: If the OP needs a specific format in Java (I admit I am still not 100 % convinced, this may be due to a misunderstanding), you are correct that it’s better to format in Java. Using `SimpleDateFormat` for that is no good idea, though, it’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. Also I don’t think your code will capitalize the month abbreviation as requested.

Comment: I am just giving him a conceptual idea. I hate spoon feeding :)